# Database AdventureWorks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build the following query in AdventureWorks:

What portions of our sales in each year (sale value) are related to individual customers and what portions of it goes for stores? The result columns should be as follow and should be sorted by year:

```
Year, Percents of sale to Individuals, Percents of sale to stores, Total value of sale
```

Any idea how?

This is what I've done so far just for individuals and I'm not sure if its correct.

```
   SELECT
   c.CustomerType,
   YEAR(oh.OrderDate) AS 'Year',
   SUM(od.LineTotal) AS 'Sale in year'

   FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail od 
   INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
   INNER JOIN Sales.Customer c ON oh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID

   GROUP BY
   YEAR(oh.OrderDate),
   c.CustomerType 

   ORDER BY YEAR(oh.OrderDate) ASC
```

[This is the output. I just don't know how to reach that

    Year, Percents of sale to Individuals, Percents of sale to stores, Total value of sale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7FEX.png)

Comment: **SHOW US** what you have tried! Where are you stuck?? We're not just going to write the whole code for you ....

Comment: @marc_s: I've added my code too and format it again :)

Comment: How much percentages should go to Individual and Store respectively?

Comment: This is what i am trying to and so I put the question here to find out this !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which version of `AdventureWorks` you have - I cannot find a `CustomerType` column in mine (SQL Server 2012 version). The type of the customer is defined on the `Person.Person` table in my case.

What I would do to solve this is the following:

- create a CTE (Common Table Expression) to sum up the sales to the individuals, grouped by year
- create a second CTE to sum up the sales to corporate customers, grouped by year

Once you have these two sets of data, it becomes rather trivial to determine the total sales per year (that's just the value from both CTE's together), and to determine the percentage of sales to individuals and corporate customers.

Here's my code - works for `AdventureWorks2012` database.

```
-- sales data for individuals, grouped by year
;WITH IndivSalesData AS
(
    SELECT
       SaleYear = YEAR(oh.OrderDate),
       SalesForYear = SUM(od.LineTotal) 
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail od 
    INNER JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
    INNER JOIN 
        Sales.Customer c ON oh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN 
        Person.Person p ON c.PersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE
        p.PersonType = 'IN'
    GROUP BY
       YEAR(oh.OrderDate)
), 
-- sales data for corporate customers, grouped by year
CorporateSalesData AS
(
    SELECT
       SaleYear = YEAR(oh.OrderDate),
       SalesForYear = SUM(od.LineTotal) 
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail od 
    INNER JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
    INNER JOIN 
        Sales.Customer c ON oh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN 
        Person.Person p ON c.PersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE
        p.PersonType = 'SC'
    GROUP BY
       YEAR(oh.OrderDate)
)
-- select the Year, determine total sales, and percentages
SELECT 
    Indiv.SaleYear, 
    PercentToIndividuals = Indiv.SalesForYear / (Indiv.SalesForYear + SC.SalesForYear) * 100.0,
    PercentToCorporate = SC.SalesForYear / (Indiv.SalesForYear + SC.SalesForYear) * 100.0,
    TotalSales = Indiv.SalesForYear + SC.SalesForYear
FROM 
    IndivSalesData Indiv
INNER JOIN 
    CorporateSalesData SC ON Indiv.SaleYear = SC.SaleYear
ORDER BY 
    Indiv.SaleYear
```

This gives me an output of:

[image]

Comment: I'm using 2008 version but thank you so much your code helped a lot :)